# CLLocationManager make my app crash having location activated

Tags: ios, swift, crash, cllocationmanager

It's weird. There are some devices that crash and some other devices that not. The thing is when having location not activated the app never dies but when I allow my app access to the location in some devices crash and in other devices not.

This is the code:

```
    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {

    if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled(){

        switch CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() {

        case .NotDetermined, .Restricted, .Denied:

            print("No access")

        case .AuthorizedAlways, .AuthorizedWhenInUse:

            let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

            longitude = self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
            latitude = self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude

            geocoder.reverseGeocodeLocation(CLLocation(latitude: (latitude), longitude: (longitude)), completionHandler: {placemarks, error in

                if error == nil && placemarks!.count > 0 {

                    self.thoroughfare = (placemarks!.last?.thoroughfare)!
                    self.city = (placemarks!.last?.locality)!

                    print(self.thoroughfare)
                    print(self.city)
                    print(self.longitude)
                    print(self.latitude)
                }
            })
            }
    } else {

        print("Location services are not enabled")

    }
}
```

When app crashes the error points to this line:

```
longitude = self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.longitude
latitude = self.locationManager.location!.coordinate.latitude
```

I've tested the app in 10 devices, having 1-2 of them that crashes at this point.

What's happening? I think I'm managing rightly what to do and what no to do when location is or not is allowed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should chek if

```
self.locationManager.location
```

Is null before using it

Comment: Did it. The app doesn't crash anymore BUT why is sometimes nil and sometimes not nil, having the location allowed?

Comment: Because location allowed doesn't mean that the data about user location is already present.

Comment: Why is that? I thought that when you allow an app access user location, you were going have granted a coordinates. Why some devices have the locationManager nil and some other not?

Comment: The user could be in an airplane or underground or somewhere else where location can't be determined. Just because you have permission to access the device location doesn't mean that the device knows where it is.

Answer (score 1):

Please try this whole code to get the location and its details.Its tried and working solution in Swift 3.0

```
import CoreLocation
import Foundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {
       let locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
        findMyLocation()

    }


       func findMyLocation(){
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyNearestTenMeters
        locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
    }
    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error)->Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("Reverse geocoder failed with error" + error!.localizedDescription)
                return
            }

            if placemarks!.count > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] 
                self.displayLocationInfo(pm)
            } else {
                print("Problem with the data received from geocoder")
                }
        })
    }

    func displayLocationInfo(_ placemark: CLPlacemark?) {
        if let containsPlacemark = placemark {
            //stop updating location to save battery life
            locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()
            let locality = (containsPlacemark.locality != nil) ? containsPlacemark.locality : ""
            let postalCode = (containsPlacemark.postalCode != nil) ? containsPlacemark.postalCode : ""
            let administrativeArea = (containsPlacemark.administrativeArea != nil) ? containsPlacemark.administrativeArea : ""
            let country = (containsPlacemark.country != nil) ? containsPlacemark.country : ""
            print(" Postal Code \(postalCode)")
            print(" administrativeArea \(administrativeArea)")
            print(" country \(country)")
            print(" locality \(locality)")
        }

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error) {
        print("Error while updating location " + error.localizedDescription)
    }
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Don't declare optional values to variable. always handle errors
Don't unwrap the location

**self.locationManager.location** // Your error

```
  if var longitude = self.locationManager.location.coordinate.longitude {
       // do your thing
    }else {
   // handle the error by declaring default value
}
```

second thing you also might receive null values even if user lost internet while getting the location or you forget the simulate the location while testing in simulator so always handle the error

Answer (score 0):

Please Check your didUpdateLocations method, you just need to check whether location is getting correctly or getting nil.

if ((self.locationManager.location) != nil){

//Get Location access here.

}